# phpMyAdmin not logging in locally

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP 5.4 set up, and now MySQL developer 5.5 both installed on my local machine and both working fine separately.

When I go to phpMyAdmin (localhost/phpmyadmin) I receive no errors and the login screen appears perfectly. Only problem I have is that I can't log in. It just comes back to the login screen when I submit login.

I figure it has something to do with the database not running on localhost or with PHP not connecting correctly to the database.

Is there anything I should look at to confirm connection between the two etc?

Take note: I have spent a few hours already Google'ing for solutions.

Comment: do check your apache logs and mysql logs for some more info.maybe your cookie etc settings are out of place?

Comment: Have you installed them both separately, or have you used a bundle (such as XAMPP?)

Comment: Please check if you have set `$cfg['blowfish_secret']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` in `config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing PHP and uninstalling MySQL and finally installing WAMP server.